# Loop over HTML class to add a different ID to each HTML element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to loop through an HTML page to check HTML elements with class="details" and then each element will that class with get an ID added to it. Of course the ID will be different for every HTML element that has class="details". Below is what I started to code, but I realized that if I have 20 HTML elements with class="details" that there has to be a way to loop or write less code to do what I want. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
        $('.details').eq(0).attr('id' , 'cLc');
        $('.details').eq(1).attr('id' , 'bLt');
```

Comment: Why would you do this on the client?  I'm 99.99% sure this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: Because the elements are being delivered via a CMS I don't have access to to add IDs to the elements so I need to create a hack on the client side to achieve what I want.

Comment: So that didn't actually answer my question.  You gave me a story about how you are getting the data, and how you want to add the IDs  to achieve what you want (which I already understood from your question), but you still haven't described what you want (the specifics of the *hack*).

Comment: Making _n_ (I'm guessing a lot) IDs for a class of elements can probably be done a better way now to avoid tremors of headaches later.

Comment: Rob helped me get to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('.details').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'id-' + idx);
});
```

Comment: Is this coding assuming the elements already have an ID? I get this error with your code. TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I think he meant `$(item).attr('id', 'id-' + idx);`. [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) returns a DOM Element not a jQuery element.

Comment: This returns all of the divs with that class, but does not add an ID.

Comment: It doesn't, but this does $('.details').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'id-' + idx);
}); Thanks for helping me to get to my answer.

Comment: You have to remove 'item' $('.details').each(function(idx) or else you get this id="id-[object HTMLDivElement]"

Comment: Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xyo34r5s/